# Short story about an author who writes a story about an unfaithful wife being murdered, and is then arrested for the murder of his own wife

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

A story of psychological horror from a '50s pulp magazine.

The protagonist is a writer, he has already published 12 parts of his story about the unfaithful wife. Suddenly the main character of his story appears and requests the writer to end the story by killing his wife. The writer unwillingly accepts his request. Next day he is arrested for the murder of the wife.

Where can I read this story?

Comment: Is this a full-length book or a short story?

Comment: It is a short story.

Comment: Another question I should've asked before: when did you read it, and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: 50s pulp magazine

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've edited the question to reflect those extra details. Should improve the chances of someone being able to correctly ID this story.

Comment: LogicDictates Thanks for lucid editing